# Deploying PHP files outside of wwwroot in Azure Web App service

Tags: php, azure, web-applications

Usually, when you deploy a PHP Web APP in Azure, you will put it under `/home/site/wwwroot` so that all scripts are accessible from the web.

However, I have some constants (like clientId + clientSecret among others) that I don't want to expose to the internet for safety reasons. I have a `constants.php` file for that purpose.

As a result, I would like to know if the following folder tree would work as expected and it's safe:

```
/home/site/wwwroot/index.php
/home/site/constants.php
```

I'm not doing the deploy and can't test it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have statements defining constants or variables in constants. php, it's safe to put them anywhere.

What you need to be aware of is that when other files load it, they will not output file contents or variables | constants for any reason.